# Passing 'build with parameters' to Jenkinsfile from scm in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am on jenkins 2.x and using pipeline.

I have configured the job to be built with param and have a string param :

[image: parameter]

I also get the Jenkinsfile from github ( pipeline from script) :

Now in my Jenkinsfile, I am using the param : ${githubUrl} and it throws error :

> stdout:  stderr: fatal: '${githubUrl}' does not appear to be a git
>   repository

So if directly write the pipeline script , this works but fetching from scm fails. Any ideas how to get around it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `url: githubUrl` without dollar sign and curve brackets. It's Groovy script, not shell script