# Use lightweight pipeline checkout from SCM with parameter as ref

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a pipeline script which is located in a very large git repo.
I can use the "Lightweight Checkout" for the "Pipeline script from SCM" (using Bitbucket) and that works fine.

However - the job needs to have a parameter BRANCH to specify which branch to get it from.

When I use "${BRANCH}" in the "Branch Specifier", I get this:

`hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/${BRANCH}:refs/remotes/origin/${BRANCH} --prune" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${BRANCH}`

Any ideas on how to do a lightweight checkout of a pipeline script for a branch that is passed as parameter?

Answer (score 3):

This is an already known bug.

Refer to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27508

You can de select 【Lightweight checkout】 to enable environment, I have tried success

Comment: Not fixed yet: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-48431

Answer (score 2):

It clearly shows that the variable BRANCH is not getting interpolated (if I am able to get it right that BRANCH is indeed the name of your branch and you have defined it somewhere). Just check if you are using single quotes while giving the parameter or double . I think that its the former case . Strings do not get interpolated in case of single quotes and it tries to find the variable in the command line i.e. an environment variable .Just change

```
'${BRANCH}'
```

to

```
"${BRANCH}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39255053/1824669) helped me although I still had to cypher that it actually applied to me.  This snipped is a bit clearer:

```
                checkout([$class : 'GitSCM',
                branches : [[name : '*/' + BRANCH]],
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations : false,
                extensions : [],
                gitTool : 'Default',
                submoduleCfg : [],
                userRemoteConfigs : [[
                    credentialsId : 'a1b1-e12f3-fake-key-f0f00f0e0000',
                    url : 'https://git.example.com/scm/foo/bar.git']]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to this field in the pipeline configuration:

[image]

It looks like this is a known issue:

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48431
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53705